# Access to array from other class

Tags: java, arrays

```
static LifeInsurance[] LIArray = new LifeInsurance[20];

public LifeInsurance ( float dMonth, int startD,int startM,int startY,int label){

    LifeInsurance.LIArray[LifeInsurance.counterLI] = this;

    this.dMonth = dMonth;
    this.startD = startD;
    this.startM = startM;
    this.startY = startY;
    this.label = Individual.l;
    this.codeLΙ = counterLI;




    counterLI++;

}
```

I've got this array in LifeInsurance class, and I want to have access to `this.label = Individual.l;`
from an other class.

How can this be possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use constructor of this class in any other class and use xxx.getLabel();

Answer (score 1):

Create a geter and setter for the static variable. Get that instance of the class to get the static variable(array in this case) and fetch the object from the array that you need . Then use the getter for label.

Answer (score 0):

To access it via class, you should do:

```
lInsurance = new LifeInsurance(args......);
lInsurance.label; //if label is visible from the class you're calling, otherwise:lI
lInsurance.getLabel(); //you'll need to define this method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create getter:

```
public String getLabel(){
    return this.label;
}
```

And call:

```
lInsurance = new LifeInsurance(args......);
lInsurance.getLabel();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle security problem with your code.  You add `this` to the package-access `LIArray` variable before `this` is fully constructed.  Another thread can therefore look at the half-constructed `this`, which can (rarely) cause all sorts of problems.

By the way, what is `CounterLI`?  You probably should use a `List` or `Map` for the list of all life insurance policies instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

leo21 is right. It seems that you want a later access to one of your Insurances, so this would be :

A getter for the Insurances array :

```
public static LifeInsurance[] getInsurances() {
    return LIArray;
}
```

Plus a getter for the required attribute :

```
public String getLabel() {
    return this.label;
}
```

Then you can access it statically from anywhere by :

```
String a_label = LifeInsurance.getInsurances()[an_index].getLabel();
```

Note : The getter for the array must be static.

It is quite a long time I haven't coded in Java, so the syntax might be incorrect (edit me if necessary), but this is the idea...